# What do you call the document that pilots get and contains the technical details of a new plane?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the document that pilots get when they have to pilot a new plane? I am wondering if there's a specific word for it or you can use any general terms such as "technical documentation", "pilots' manual", "pilots' booklet", "technical manuscript". What's the official word for it and does the document contain specifications for the components of the airplane and not just how to pilot it? Because if it doesn't, then probably it's not the word I am looking for unless pilots don't ever get briefed or informed on the components of the planes. Think of the pilots before piloting the Boeing 737.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boeing seems to use the term [**flight crew operations manual**](https://jupiter.euroatlantic.pt/FILES/lbl/blb_7778_8514/FCOM%20B767%20-%20Only%20Rev.%2027.pdf), and yes, it looks like it includes extensive technical information and not just instructions for flying the plane.

I have also seen "pilot's manual," flight manual," and "operations manual," but I don't know whether or to what degree all these terms are interchangeable.